# List in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have some issues with a `listview` in a Fragment.
I want to show a List with Fruits in the Fragment, tried a few things but.
In a later version the `String[]` should contain data from a json object.

This is the current status:

```
public class fragmentA extends Fragment
    implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView textView;
ViewStub viewStub;
ListFragment listView;

static final String[] FRUITS = new String[] { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana",
        "Blueberry", "Coconut", "Durian", "Guava", "Kiwifruit",
        "Jackfruit", "Mango", "Olive", "Pear", "Sugar-apple" };

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  savedInstanceState) {
     // das Layout fuer dieses Fragment laden
     View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenta, container, false);
     // inflate layout
     Button notfallbtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.notfallbtn);

    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
   // listView = (ListFragment) view.findViewById(R.id.einkaufsliste);
    viewStub = (ViewStub) view.findViewById(R.id.viewStub);
    viewStub.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // initialize button using the inflated view object
    notfallbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    // listener for button

   setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.einkaufsliste,FRUITS));

   ListView listView = getListView();
   listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int position, long id) {
           // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });


    return view;   // return inflated view
 }
```

The error messages I get:

> Cannot resolve 'setListAdapter'
>
> Cannot resolve 'einkaufsliste'

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public class fragmentA extends Fragment`

does not extend `ListFragment`. `setListAdapter` is a method of `ListFragment`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

Also you probably need

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,FRUITS)
```

Instead of `this` use `getActivity()` which returns the activity this fragment is associated with.

Also read

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Also override onActivityCreated and use `ListView lv = getListView()`.

Comment: also getListView can not be called inside onCreateView

Comment: this help for the setListadapter, but still get an error "cannot resolve einkaufsliste" and Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), have the same error :/

Comment: @johnbob that is also answered see the edit. You can use a in build layout or you need to have a layout by that name